# How do you apply z-index on parallax image

Tags: css

I am trying to overlap my survey form over a parallax image (creating using MateralizeCss) using Z-index. However, my form still remains under the image. Please help! *Cant provide my codes as it is in xslt. Any simple example will be appreciated.

This is the html code

```
  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
      <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/parallax1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%;margin: 0 auto ;z-index:1000;background-color:white;padding:2.5%; box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px gray, &#xD;&#xA;        -5px 4px 7px gray, 5px 4px 7px gray;margin-bottom:5%;position:absolute">
    <div style="font-size:250%;font-weight:bold">In Store Hub Trooper Feedback Form</div>
    <div style="font-size:150%;">Q number</div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div style="font-size:150%;">Dateeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
    <div id="input">
      <input type="date" class="datepicker" required="required">
      </input>
      <span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: To work z-index, you need to add a position to the element, too.

Comment: @NadezhdaSerafimova i did. i added position:absolute

Comment: Probably the form has lower z-index than the image. Can't you add a fiddle only with the section?

Comment: i have updated it.

Comment: it would be better & more maintainable for you if you put your CSS in a stylesheet and not in the style attribute.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow ya, you are right. i will do that when i am working on the actual product.

Comment: that's good. Anyway, let me know if you need me to edit my answer, but you should be able to figure it out from there plus my CodePen.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow it works now! Thanks!!!

Comment: you're welcome. Liked the picture of Burano too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the form and the image will need a `position` property.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform" class="overlap">
  <button id="button" name="button">A button</button>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div class="box">
  Thing overlapping with form
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 3em;
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6em;
  right: 20%;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3em;
  width: 25%;
}
```

I made you a CodePen:

See the Pen [Overlapping things with z-index](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere/pen/RpYmvR/) by Yvonne Aburrow ([@vogelbeere](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

**EDIT**: I added my answer before you updated the question with your code.